# Is there an Android app that can replace pieces by dots?

Tags: blindfold-chess, android

I would like to learn blindfolded chess. But after about 20 moves I cannot remember the position.

My question: Do you know an app for Android that can replace the pieces by dots?

For Desktop PC I found Babaschess. In the install folder there are the pieces as gifs, which can be replaced.

Looks like on the pic (A Ruy Lopez).

Is there an Android app that has this feature?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on some other Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish Why do you think it belongs somewhere else? It's 100% focused on chess.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Ik it is related to chess a bit but it isn't 100% about chess. OP is asking for an Android app. Some other SE websites will be able to answer this in a better way.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish In my opinion the subject trumps the medium though. If OP asked for a good book on the Ruy Lopez, would you send them to a forum about books?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni It's not about that! You need to understand which SE is better for which type of questions.